# Mix classes and use cases in PlantUML diagram

Tags: plantuml

I try to create a diagram which contains the class hierarchy as well as use cases which use the classes. I tried to use PlantUML today, but somehow one cannot mix these two diagram types. This is the simplest file I could come up with:

```
@startuml
class Foo
usecase Bar
@enduml
```

When I only have one of these lines in there, it works fine. But with both lines I get this:

```
❯ plantuml text.txt
Error line 5 in file: text.txt
Some diagram description contains errors
```

Is there some way to put both into the diagram, or is that just impossible?

Answer (score 5):

I had used PlantUML 1.2021.0. This apparently doesn't contain the `allowmixing` feature, that the current version 1.2021.14 supports. Upgrading the software and adding `allowmixing` to the file cures this problem.

```
@startuml
allowmixing
class Foo
usecase Bar
@enduml
```

[image]